# Tuning the ShieldUi JavaScript chart mouse out event

Tags: javascript, shieldui

I have a Shield UI JavaScript bar chart. And need to take use of the seriesMouseOut event. I am actually using the both mouseOver/Mouse Out events but the second one seems to work only when the mouse leaves the data plot area. I assume it makes sense for the seriesMouseOut event to be triggered when I move the mouse away from each of the bars.
I use this piece of code to test:

```
events: {
 seriesMouseOver: function(args) {
    document.getElementById("info").innerHTML ="Mouse OVER " + args.domEvent.timeStamp;
},
seriesMouseOut: function(args) {
    document.getElementById("info").innerHTML ="Mouse Out " + args.domEvent.timeStamp;
},
},
```

I went through the documentation but didn’t find any additional properties to be set. On the other hand the seriesMouseOver event works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually in need to set one more property. By default the completeSeriesTrace if true. This means that the seriesMouseOut will occur only after the mouse pointer has left the dataPlot area.
If you need the event to occur right after the bar has been left you need to set it to false:

```
seriesSettings: {
        bar: {
            enablePointSelection: true,
            completeSeriesTrace: false
        }, 
}
```